# (How to) customize the active window/program icons shown in the desktop panel

Tags: linux, xfce, desktop, panel

Driving me nuts!

For quite a while I'm searching for a possibility to customize the active/opened program icons shown in my horizontal panel. I'm using xfce4.
Most of the program icons using my installed theme (blue icons) by doing nothing else but using an xcfe4 custom launcher with a manually assigned icon from my installed theme.
With others (Keepass, Notepadqq, DBeaver, ...) this seems to be not enough.

Does anybody have a clue **if** this is possible at all and if yes **how** to do this?

[image: Screen]

---

Edit:

- Im using xfce4-(standard)-panels
  [image: Screen]
- Icon theme was manually installed (downloaded and just moved to /usr/share/icons/)
- Icon for each (and every) application I'm using was then manually chosen by adding and editing the launcher Infos like shown in the pic. This I did for all programs seen in the left vertical panel (also for the programs shown in the screen of the horizontal panel with active programs like DBeaver, Keepass, Firefox, ...).
  [image: Screen]
- Some active/opened programs are using the icon(s) from the launcher
  [image: Screen]
- ... and some don't
  [image: Screen]

Comment: What launcher are you using? What panel are you using? What version of the apps are you running (launcher and panel apps)? How did you install the icon theme? Are you sure the theme has icons for those specific apps?

Comment: I ve edited the post. Hope its now a bit more clear...

Comment: I'm not on xfce and can't be sure if all apps shown on your panel draw icons from the same place. Doing this all by hand seems rather tedious, why didn't you use the `Appearance` preference tool provided by xfce? Try installing your icon theme system-wide through that tool, it has an Icons tab. You should generate an icon cache beforehand with `gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/your-icon-theme-folder` so as to reduce memory usage when icons are drawn. Try this and if you still have issues provide your distribution and icon theme link so I can check it locally.

Comment: Before assigning them manually i didnt know that it would let me choose from these icons when adding a new program to my panel. After a while i did use Appeance for updating the system wide icons automaticly what works. But even after re-assigning  program icons in the panel the way you proposed nothing changed. I guess it has something to do with antis wrote here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/579610/changing-application-icon-in-window-buttons-xfce-panel-item
Im guessing already some icons just cant be changed if a program doesnt allow it cause some used icons are not configurable...

Comment: Thats the theme im using: https://www.xfce-look.org/p/1333360/

Comment: Forget to mention my distribution: gentoo. Its not providing the theme by any package manger so i was installing it manually like like described in the theme link.

Comment: have you tried ```gtk-update-icons-cache```? Your System Settings should be able to read the icon theme from the cache and you should be able to install it system-wide from there.

Comment: Yep...i tried but nothing changed.